# Multiprocessing from imported module doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a problem with multiprocessing when importing a module, which can be represented with the following example.

I have a module named `tmp1.py` with the following content:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mul2(x):
    return [a*2 for a in x]

def calculate(func, x):
    r = []
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Pool(2)
        r.append(p.map(func, x))
        p.close(), p.join()
    return r
```

I import it to another file `tmp2.py` with the following content:

```
import tmp1

inputs = [[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]    

result = tmp1.calculate(tmp1.mul2, inputs)
print(result)
```

What I expect after running it, are values of the input multiplied by 2. However, after I run it all I get is an empty list.
I work on Windows, python 3.10.

If I copy-paste all the content of `tmp1.py` to `tmp2.py` and adapt the function calls it works fine.

Where's the problem?

Comment: `__name__` does not equal `'__main__'` in an imported module so the Pool isn't created.

Comment: You are copying code without understanding what it is you're doing.  `__name__ == '__main__'` is not a magical incantation used by multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if __name__ == '__main__':` is required to control code that creates new processes on platforms such as Windows that use the *spawn* method for creating new processes.

When the *spawn* method is being used the child process is created by creating an "empty" process, i.e. one that inherits nothing from the main process, into which a new Python interpreter is launched. This new interpreter must re-read all the source files already referenced in order to execute all statements at global scope in order to re-create global variables, function definitions, etc. in the new child process's address space before invoking, in your case, function `tmp1.mul2`. In the new process `__name__` will *not* be `'__main__'` and therefore we will *not* be re-executing recursively the code that created this new process to begin with.

The code that creates new processes *at global scope*, which is the scope we need to concern ourselves with, is actually in the main script, specifically `result = tmp1.calculate(tmp1.mul2, inputs)`. It is this code that needs to be within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block:

**File *tmp2.py***

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tmp1

    inputs = [[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]]

    result = tmp1.calculate(tmp1.mul2, inputs)
    print(result)
```

I have put within the block all global statements that do not need to be executed within the new child process in order for it to have its storage initialized with whatever it might need for execution, i.e. all of the *tmp2.py* code.

Then *tmp1.py* becomes:

```python
def mul2(x):
    return [a*2 for a in x]

def calculate(func, x):
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    r = []
    p = Pool(2)
    r.append(p.map(func, x))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return r
```

The above prints:

```None
[[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18]]]
```

This is a list of a single list. Perhaps, you really want:

```python
def mul2(x):
    return [a*2 for a in x]

def calculate(func, x):
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    p = Pool(2)
    r = p.map(func, x)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    return r
```

The prints:

```None
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18]]
```